# Why do armatures have two edit modes?

Tags: rigging, armature, edit-mode

everyone,
I have a pretty minor question that has been bugging me for a while. When I create an armature and then press the tab key, a pie menu with three options comes up: Edit, Edit Mode, and Pose Mode. Does anyone know what the difference between the Edit and Edit Mode is?

Thanks!

[image: armature edit mode screenshot]

Comment: that's weird, you should only have Edit Mode, what does it give when you choose Edit?

Comment: It gives me the expected pie menu of Object, Edit, and Pose:

Comment: Here is a screenshot:

Comment: I can't seem to upload another screenshot, but you get the idea.

Comment: Looks like a Bug, the armature only have Object mode, Edit mode and Pose mode

Comment: I only get the pie menu if I press Ctrl+Tab, and only if I do that in Edit Mode. If I press Tab it toggles between Object Mode and Edit Mode. If I press Ctrl+Tab in Object Mode it goes into Pose Mode. Ctrl+Tab in Edit Mode gives me a pie with Object Mode, Pose Mode and Edit Mode. The fact that I don't get it for Tab may because of some setting that I changed so long ago that I've forgotten about it.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is a bit subtle.  If you were to enable 'Interface: 3d Viewport pie menus' add on,  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>–<kbd>Tab</kbd> will give pie menus in Object mode instead of changing modes:

[image: Object mode pie menus]

As you can see, the top menu item is "Edit Mode" and the bottom is "Edit" as in your example.  If you have Python tooltips enabled and hover over each, you will find that "Edit Mode" *toggles* edit mode, but "Edit" forces the mode to edit.

This is useful with the addon, because you get the same menu in edit mode, so you can remember that <kbd>8</kbd> is the shortcut to toggle after you've typed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>–<kbd>Tab</kbd> in either mode.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I am glad that it is a deliberate feature and not a bug or conflict between add-ons. Thanks, Marty Fouts!